# How to fix "DeprecationWarning: You passed a bytestring as `filenames`"?

Tags: python

I have a piece of code as follows (running with python 2.7.12):

```
self.config = ConfigParser()
self.config.read(self.config_file)
```

where `self.config_file` is of type `string`, but when running this piece inside a much more complex code (python-selenium with py.test) I get a warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: You passed a bytestring as `filenames`. This will not work on Python 3. Use `cp.read_file()` or switch to using Unicode strings across the board.
self.config.read(self.config_file)
```

When trying to create a small code example, I do not get this warning anymore.

Maybe there is an easy way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the bytes into a string using the `decode` method:

```
self.config.read(self.config_file.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error has the solution. Change the `self.config_file` argument to unicode using

```
self.config.read(unicode(self.config_file,"utf-8"))
```